# Regex: Find al words between <em> and </em> html tags, that have no space before `<em>` and after `</em>`

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

See this sentence below:

**A space of creation conceived as a `<em>full</em>`attributed to myself.**

You see that is no space before and after `</em>`

So, I need to find al words between  html tags, that have no space before `<em>` and after `</em>`, and to make a replacement as to put a new space before/after.

Of course, the simple solution is to make a simple search and replace  with  `(space)</em>(space)` , but a regex will be much better, so as not to be 2 spaces like can be in simple replace.

I try this, but I believe the replacement is not working:

FIND: `(?!\w)(<em>.*?</em>)(?!\w)`

REPLACE BY:  `\1 \2 \3`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  - [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: I edit my post and add my regex solution. I believe the replace is not good. Something is not working. Anyway, I find myself the solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

**This regex will add a space before and after *|* if there is none.**

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?!\x20)(<em>.*?</em>)(?!\x20)`
- Replace with: `\x20\1\2\3\x20`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Could you explain how the regular expression works at least? It is an answer to a very specific beginners problem. Without explaining how the solution works, I see not much value to other users.

Comment: simple. My regex will add a space before and after <em>|</em> if there are non.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the additional information instead of adding it as a comment. You are here for nearly 6 years, you should know how it goes.